# What could be the reason of Bing API key not working?

Tags: search-engine, bing-api

I have been trying to work with `Bing API` to make a custom search engine. I obtained a free `Bing Search API` which work perfectly when I tried to use it using `azure marketplace` website. But wheneever I tried using it the URL like

http://api.bing.net/json.aspx?Appid=m/gNRFAX3faTfrm+81uVSTHPJkf/Dimn2DTM7NyukpU=&query=sushi&sources=web.

I get error saying

```
Parameter has invalid value.
```

So I tried using JavaScript and PHP same error accompanies every time. Any idea why it is happening?

Note: I did not put my original API key here.

Comment: @Neeraj T: I subscribed basic plan of bing search api. But i dont know where the appid or app key is. will u tell me the way to get app id.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually that API using the parameter `AppId` is deprecated. You have to use azure bing API. Use access token as value or client key. Please look at this [link](https://datamarket.azure.com/developer/applications/).

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify this Appid 49EB4B94127F7C7836C96DEB3F2CD8A6D12BDB71 
Check it out: http://api.bing.net/xml.aspx?Appid=49EB4B94127F7C7836C96DEB3F2CD8A6D12BDB71&query=girls&sources=web&web.count=40&web.offset=41

Comment: I subscribed basic plan of **bing search api**. But i dont know where the appid or app key is. will u tell me the way to get app id.? @Adrian Statescu